# How do I to make compatible DataSet on IE8 in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer-8

I did a RSS feed in ASP.net. However, I noticed that the "DataSet" doesn't work with IE8 but only on Google Chrome. Do you have a solution to make it compatible with IE ?

I use the asp:repeater to display the RSS.

Code behind :

```
private void GetRSS()
        {
            //Création de la requete Web à partir d'un lien XML
            WebRequest rssReq = WebRequest.Create("http://www.leparisien.fr/actualites-a-la-une.rss.xml");

            //On Crée le proxy
            WebProxy px = new WebProxy("http://www.leparisien.fr/actualites-a-la-une.rss.xml", true);

            //On assigne le proxy à la requete Web
            rssReq.Proxy = px;

            //On mets un TimeOut pour ne pas faire de boucle infinie
            rssReq.Timeout = 5000;
            try
            {
                //On obtient la reponse du serveur
                WebResponse rep = rssReq.GetResponse();

                //On lit la réponse via un XmlTextReader
                XmlTextReader xtr = new XmlTextReader(rep.GetResponseStream());

                //Création d'un DataSet
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                //On lit la réponse dans le DataSet
                ds.ReadXml(xtr);

                //On "attache" les liens aux tables du tableau

                rssRepeater.DataSource = ds.Tables[2];
                rssRepeater.DataBind();
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
                {
                    if (((HttpWebResponse)ex.Response).StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                    {
                        // on gère l'erreur 404 ici
                    }
                }
                else if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.NameResolutionFailure)
                {
                    // handle name resolution failure
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing the server-side .Net `DataSet` class and the client-side DOM `dataset` property.

Those have nothing to do with eachother; you don't actually have a problem.